# Is it possible to put the phrase "as of now" in front an noun as an adjective?

Tags: phrases

For example:

> An (as of now) incomplete piece of junk (To express this the piece of junk could be finished later on)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense in colloquial English... but the implication *could* be that it *was* working at one time and is now a "boat anchor" (i.e., useful only as dead weight).

It might be better to phrase it as, "An (as yet) incomplete piece of junk," or "An (as yet) unfinished project."